# Mocking a HttpHandler for HttpClient, handle method returning null

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am mocking a HttpHandler class because i want to create a mock backend for my application for testing purposes. I created my own HttpHandler and i passed it as an argument in a HttpClient constructor. The code in the handle method is executed, but the return statemets returns always null, could you help me determine why does it always return null instead of what i hardcoded for it to return in the backend mock? Here is my code:

mockBackend.ts

```
import { HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


export class MockBackend extends HttpHandler{
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  //some random token for testing purposes
  token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkFkYW0iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9.AvFr350SliijG44Rl6mX21p5eTKNcDkxb4n2ndPTep8';

  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (req.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') &&
      req.method === 'post') {
        let body = JSON.parse(req.body);
        if (body.login === "Adam" && body.password === "Adam") {
          return of(new HttpResponse({
            status: 200,
            body: {token: this.token}
          }));
        } else {
          return of(new HttpResponse({status: 401}));
        }
      }

      if (req.url.endsWith('/api/orders') && req.method === 'get') {
        if (req.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer ' + this.token) {
          return of(new HttpResponse({status: 200, body: [1, 2, 3]}));
        } else {
          return of(new HttpResponse({status: 401}));
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
    return of(new HttpResponse({status: 404}));
  }

}
```

Here is my HttpClient factory

```
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MockBackend } from './mockBackend';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export function fakeBackendFactory(
  backend: MockBackend) {

    return new HttpClient(backend);
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
  provide: HttpClient,
  useFactory: fakeBackendFactory,
  deps: [MockBackend]
};
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FollowersComponent } from './followers/followers.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { FollowersService } from './followers/followers.service';
import { FollowerComponent } from './follower/follower.component';
import { Error404Component } from './error404/error404.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './login-form/login-form.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { NoAccessComponent } from './no-access/no-access.component';

import { fakeBackendProvider } from './shared/fakeBackendFactory';
import { HttpRequest, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MockBackend } from './shared/mockBackend';
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'followers', component: FollowersComponent },
  { path: 'follower/:id', component: FollowerComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'no-access', component: NoAccessComponent },
  { path: '**', component: Error404Component }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FollowersComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FollowerComponent,
    Error404Component,
    LoginFormComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    NoAccessComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  providers: [
    FollowersService,
    AuthService,
    MockBackend,
    fakeBackendProvider,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My authservice which calls httpClient post method:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    console.log('AuthService: ', httpClient);
  }

  login(credentials) {
    return this.httpClient.post('/api/authenticate', credentials);
  }

  logout() {

  }

  isLoggedIn() {

  }
}
```

my component which uses the service, in it the result of authService.login is always null

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css']
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {

  invalidLogin: boolean;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    login: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(14)]),
    password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(14)])
  });

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
      this.authService.login({login: this.login.value, password: this.password.value})
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log('result: ',result);
        if (result) {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        } else {
          this.invalidLogin = true;
        }
      });
  }

  get login() {
    return this.loginForm.get('login');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.loginForm.get('password');
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? You can achieve this mock-up much more easily IMO.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your `handle()` method will always return `of(new HttpResponse({status: 404}));`. Anything that's inside `setTimeout()` it is not directly bound to `handle`'s execution context, so every return statement inside there is bound to the callback's context.

Comment: @AndreiGătej you were correct, also the reason why i thought http requests returned only null was because i was not returning any "body" property in HttpResponse object, which resulted with a null value in console.